# Is it legally required for districts to be contiguous?

Tags: united-states

I was reading about [Shaw v. Reno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaw_v._Reno), a case about a congressional district that was altered on the basis of the race of its voters.

Is there a law (precedent or statutory) which requires congressional districts to be contiguous? I was thinking that you could gerrymander much more effectively if you could make up a district from multiple unconnected parts.

The oddly shaped district in question:

[image: NC's twelfth district]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; only 23 states *require* their congressional districts to be contiguous.

See [*Reapportionment and Redistricting in the West* by Gary F. Moncrief](https://books.google.com/books?id=VYICdjpivIQC&lpg=PA24&ots=lti9Hoc9xm&dq=%2223%20states%22%20contiguous%20district&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Only 23 states have [contiguity] requirements for their congressional districts, although as a practical matter most congressional districts will be contiguous; the relative dearth of legal limits is a manifestation of the fact that few states have provided any express legal constraints on congressional districting at all.

But that's not to say more states don't have contiguous districts. On [Profesor Justin Levitt's website](http://redistricting.lls.edu/where-state.php#contiguity), he observes that:

> Many states require contiguity only "to the extent possible," and
>   courts generally accept anomalies that otherwise seem reasonable in
>   context.

I am having a difficult time finding a list of states with such requirements; I will update if I find it.